# write mathematical equation in ggpplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

hopefully I have a very simple question. 
I am trying to plot a mathematical equation to my scatterplot using:

```
  annotate("text",x=600, y=3.5e-04,label="y==~3.57~10^{-05}~x~-~2.79~10^{-05}",parse=TRUE,fontface="italic")
```

which gives me almost what I would like to have [equation as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1H7X.png)

now, as you can see from my code I would like the equation to be plotted with (1) italic letters, and (2) even more important to get a * between the numbers and the exponential as 3.75 * 10... 
it seems so easy but whatever attempt i try i get an error saying "unexpected '*'".
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work, using expression/italic and paste to get a text object and adding it to annotate:

```
annotate("text",x=600, y=3.5e-04,label=paste(expression(italic(y == 3.57 %.% 10^-05 %*% -2.79 %.% 10^-05))),parse=TRUE)
```

I tried some things using this ref: http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/ and I think the tildes next to the multiplication symbol produced an error